# Magic Number - The Quest for the Simplest

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Is there any better logic that can be applied to magic numbers?
Or is there a magic number that I am missing out on?
Please help me out with this simplest working code!

> A Magic number is a number whose sum of digits eventually leads to 1.
>
> Example#1:  19 ;  1+9 =10 ; 1+0 = 1.  Hence a magic number.
>
> Example#2:  226; 2+2+6=10; 1+0 =1.  Hence a magic number.
>
> Example#3:  874; 8+7+4=19; 1+9=10; 1+0=1.  Hence a magic number.

```java
boolean isMagic ( int n ) {
  return n % 9 == 1;
}
```

Comment: You are speaking about "magic number". You should include a definition because not everyone knows what a magic number is. Additionally, your examples calculate the sum of digits, but your code simply does a modulo operation. They have nothing in common. So ... What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have already put a definition before the code so that everyone can understand the code, and and using the modulo operation breaks the code in just few lines and Is working with most of the examples. The actual code can be written by any kid, So I decided to do this. If there is any mistake is getting any Magic Number please let me know.

Comment: Argh. You are right. The definition is there. I only read the examples. Sorry. But still, your code has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Can you just help me improve the code? This is the simplest code for magic number which I have found to be working with almost all examples. And the point is -
 it works beyond the logic of the definition given.

Comment: @Godfather : this is more of an mathamatical algorithm problem than code. Have you proved that " `n` is a magic number if and only if `n%9 = 1` " ?

Comment: You do know that you could just write those three lines inside the method as `return n % 9 == 1;` right?

Comment: And the mathematics is fine, but your teacher may be expecting you to prove that this is correct.  The proof is extremely easy, but that doesn't mean you can omit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not 100% that the code you placed would work to get a "magic number", but my approach to the problem would be different.
First, I'd receive a String, so that I can get the different digits of the number with a `String.charat`.
Then I'd use a while cycle to sum the numbers until it gets a single digit number, then check if it's 1.

The code would be

```
boolean isMagicNumber(String number) {
    
    int[] digits = new int[number.length()];
    int sum = 99;

    while(sum/10 >= 1) {
          sum = 0;
          for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
              sum += Integer.parseInt(""+number.charAt(i));
          }
          if(sum == 1) {
               return true;
          }
    }
    return false;
}
```

There might be a better solution, but this is what I'd do to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanx for the Code but its too lengthy it can be chopped down to more precise and small code.